# Does liquibase support jdbc mysql connection urls in local.properties file?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, liquibase

When running liquibase commands (status, update) with `url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydbname"` in a liquibase.local.properties file I receive the following error.

```
Liquibase status Failed: 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
Connection could not be created to "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydbname" with driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.  
Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

If I run the same command but pass the url in on the command line it works.

Comment: Is there really no more to the exception than that?

Comment: That is the complete exception. I have added line breaks. :)

Comment: Do you really have double quotes around the URL in the properties file? If yes, try removing them

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because the mysql driver is not in your classpath. Liquibase is recognizing the URL and trying to configure com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as the driver to use, but it appears to not be able to find it.